# How to call functions from JS to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im probably way off the mark here but I'm trying to self teach JS and am having problems with correct ways to call functions and relate it back to HTML.
I'm not sure if my password function is even correct.
Any help or mini-lessons are much appreciated

```
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1>Password Generator</h1>
</div>
<div class="viewer">
<p id="view">test</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
<button onclick="generate();">Generate</button>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<p></p>
</div>
 <script src="c:\tesweb\testjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
function password(){
 var retVal = "";
 var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#@$&!?";
 var length = 8;

for (var i = 0, n = chars.length; i < length; i++) {
  retVal += chars.charAt(Math.Floor(Math.random() * n));
  }
 return x = retVal;
}

function generate() {
    document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to do a lot better than Mozilla's resources. Have fun! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One huge tip: Try out the debugging tools in your browser (for example the Console in Chrome). This will give you a lot of information.

For example, when running your code and clicking the 'Generate' button this error is shown in the Console log: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined'

That makes sense, because in the generate() function you use x, but it is not defined there. You do have a password() function as well, but you are not using/calling it.

Think of it this way: a function often receives an input, does something with that input, and then returns an output. But a function will only be run if you call it.

In your case, the password() function does not receive an input, but it does generate a random string as output.

To fix your code, you simply have to call the password() function. You can put the result in that 'x' variable if you want (or in a variable with any other name).

Your generate() function would then look like this:

```
function generate() {
    var x = password();
    document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = x;
}
```

What do we do now? We set the x variable to the output of the password() function and we then display that as HTML on the element with id 'view'.

Note that the `x` variable could also be named `anything` here.

Now, let's run the code again and check the Chrome Console log again... A new error: Uncaught TypeError: Math.Floor is not a function

Ok, so we're making progress. the `floor` function actually needs to be all lowercase (floor vs. Floor). So let's change that as well. And run the code again...

And it's working!

But even though it's working, you're not returning the output in the password() function in the correct way. you should simply `return retVal;` instead of `return x = retVal;`

In a function, you are supposed to just return something, so the output can be used or assigned to a variable somewhere. The reason that 'x = retVal' also works here, is that it will simply set x equal to retVal, and then return x.. (instead of simply returning retVal directly).

I hope you understand what I am saying. I know it's difficult to get started with programming, and it takes a bit of time to realize how functions are supposed to work.

Here is the full JS code with corrections:

```
function password() {
  var retVal = "";
  var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#@$&!?";
  var length = 8;

  for (var i = 0, n = chars.length; i < length; i++) {
    retVal += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }
  return retVal;
}

function generate() {
  var x = password();
  document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help @wesley-synio
Your explanations are spot on, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the value, as it won't do anything with it. If you were calculating something, and needed to run a function to get a value, you'd return. For this, you just use `retVal` to set the innerHTML of `view`. Take a look at my snippet for the answer. :)

```js
function generate() {
    var length = 8,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    // After it's done, you just set the innerHTML of whatever element you want to display it
    document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = retVal;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h1>Password Generator</h1>
</div>
<div class="viewer">
<p id="view">test</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
<button onclick="generate();">Generate</button>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<p></p>
</div>
```